# Is there a way to set an expiry on Firebase refresh tokens?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I understand that the ID token are JWT with an expiry. However, I am curious if there is a way to set some sort of expiry on the refresh token given by Firebase sign in that allows us to call Firebase to get a fresh ID token - AFAIK these never expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh tokens don't expire after a certain time interval. The Firebase documentation on [managing user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) says:

> Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:
>
> - The user is deleted
> - The user is disabled
> - A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates)

But you *can* revoke the refresh token (since it's really just an OAuth2 token). See the documentation on [revoking refresh tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) for more on that.

Comment: Got it - so to accomplish something like this I could queue it in my backend to revoke at some given time. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on the goal of revoking it, which I wasn't really clear on. For example: if you want to disable the user from logging in, there is a separate setting for that.